# Facebook API - Notifications for mobile

Tags: facebook, api

Using facebook api, I managed to send notifications perfectly fine, however I noticed that notifications can only be sent to facebook users that are not on mobile.. So all mobile users get NO notifications until they are on a PC.

My app is using 'Facebook canvas', and 'Website' in the developer settings.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Just use push notifications for mobile

Comment: is there no other way, making apps for windows/ios/android is too tedious :(

Answer (score 0):

> The notifications are only surfaced on the desktop web version of Facebook

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/appnotifications